# Change background color Magento 2 header panel and compile less on Staging server

Tags: magento2, less, static-content, compilation, staging

In `/app/design/frontend/MyThemeName/my-theme/web/css/source/_theme.less` I added  `@header-panel__background-color: @color-green-green1;`

To change the background color of the header panel (I have a child-theme based on Luma theme).

After I made changes in `_theme.less` I did on my *Local environment*:

- `rm -R pub/static/*`
- `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy nl_NL`

But the only way to see my changes is when I go to my Magento Admin panel and *Flush Static Files Cache* in the admin panel.

**1)** Is there a method to do this using command line only?

(anyway locally my changes are visible now)

---

Now I commit `_theme.less` and push it to my remote repository. From this remote repository I pull `_theme.less` into my *Staging server* and run the following commands, to compile my less on the `Staging server`:

- rm -R pub/static/*
- bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy nl_NL

**2)** But I can't get my changes visible in the front-end on the `Staging server`? What do I have to do?

Answer (score 2):

In your Magento directory issue command :

```
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/\*; rm -rf pub/static/\*
```

reload page